# New Bluemix app not reflecting changes

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

I'm missing a linkage somewhere. I created a new app from template, semi cloned my other app, but when I hit the URL, I only see the template app.

Due to a server disappearing (temporarily), I needed to clone my app and create one that used a different route to different servers (and a few other small changes).  My clone process was probably sad, but I just used the nodeJS/Cloudant template.  I then disconnected/deleted that Cloudant and connected the other Cloudant (to avoid having to reload). I connected the Watson Personality Insights service from the other app as well.  I then configured it for git, cloned, moved the code from the other app in ... and commit/pushed it.  If I use the Bluemix dashboard to see my code, it is what I expect.  But if I select the app, it still shows the template app.  I have recycled several times.  Have verified all code is correct.  Have even gone into Build/Deploy and created a build stage (which probably wasn't needed) ... but if I use the URL ... I still see the old app.  In all of git, there is no code for the old app, and a git pull locally says that I am up to date.  How do I sync up the code git sees, and the code that the app is using when I hit the URL?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had similar once, but it was just one file impacted.  It was after similar hacking about.  I made a random comment change and the next commit/push picked up on it.  In your case getting rid of cache and then forcing a re-stage might help better.

```
cf set-env app_name NODE_MODULES_CACHE false
cf restage app_name
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. Absurdly tight 2/15 deliverable.  Will be testing right after that. Thanks